# Switch outlet combo Help

Tags: receptacle, light

I've just bought my first home and the building inspector pointed out some outlets that were not grounded and this one that has its polarity reversed.

This is an outlet and light switch. There are 4 wires inside; a ground, a white (neutral) and two black wires. I've already followed other posts here and identified the hot wire and its location, bottom right screw, and the neutral wire and it's location on the left silver screw.

Where does this second black wire go, that isn't hot?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you take some pictures to clarify what's inside the box?

Comment: More detail, please. Is this conduit or cables? Do all the wires come in together? It's odd to have two blacks and just one white. Please revise your post to clarify.

Comment: Figured out how to add photos and added a few photos.

Comment: It's difficult to tell that there is a black "hot" wire in the hot photo, but I promise you there is a hot wire there.

Comment: When taking photos of dark recesses like outlet boxes, it's normally better to turn on your camera flash.  It would be helpful to have a better photo straight-on of the box insides, maybe bend the switch/outlet down out of the way a bit?

Answer (score 1):

The second black is almost certainly "switched hot" going from the switch to whatever the switch controls.

The terminal layout of these combined switches can vary, so the best way to check which is which is to look at the diagram that came with the switch, or see if there's labelling on the body of the switch itself. If one of the terminals is labelled "load", that's the connection for the switch's output.

Comment: The light switch is just a simple light above the sink. I'm unsure whether it is suppose to go on the top right screw, above the hot, or the top left screw above the neutral?

Answer (score -1):

Here is a diagram showing the wiring in a typical switch/outlet combo - some may differ as @keshlam notes. The left image uses european(?) wiring colors, not US colors, but the wire IDs are the same.

The bottom outlet needs hot, neutral(N) and ground(G/E); you have already identified these in your setup. As you noted, hot connects to bottom right.

A key aspect of such devices is that there is normally a ***metal electrical connection*** on the side between the top and bottom screws ("***Break away Fin Tab***" in right diagram). This can be removed (broken off) but if present electrically joins the top and bottom screws on that side.  **Your current photo of the right side of the switch is not clear enough to tell if you have this tab still in place.**

**If you do have the tab**, then the upper right screw needs no additional connection and should just be tightened down.

**If you do not have the tab**, another hot wire ("line hot") needs to be connected to that upper right screw.

**In either case**, the wire heading out to whatever the switch controls ("switch load", probably the un-energized black wire, but make sure) needs to be connected to upper left screw.

[image]

**Important note on wiring workmanship:**

Watch out for screw terminal wiring.
Make sure screws are securely tightened down - non-secure tightening can lead to poor connections, electrical arcing, and fire. The screws should be pressing only on bare wire, not partly on wire insulation, and should cover the whole "hook" part of the wire. Wires should be kept as far away from each other as practicable in close quarters. Try to minimize the length of bare wire not covered by the screw. To minimize the chances of stray bare wire wrongly contacting a screw or other metal once the device is pushed back inside the box, many electricians wrap a few turns of good quality (e.g. Scotch) electrical tape all around the perimeter of the device sides, covering the screws/bare metal.

Comment: Curious to know what exactly was unhelpful here - I'm stumped.